# Format number, don't show zeros in the decimal part

Tags: javascript

I have a decimal number which is displayed as following:

```
<nested:text property="product.price" maxlength="5" onclick="javascript:validatePriceValue(this);"/>
```

| number | displayed as |
| --- | --- |
| 44 | 44.00 |

I wanna using javascript display only 44 and not 44.00

How can I do?

Comment: You forgot to post your current code. Please edit the question and add it.

Comment: you can use `parseInt`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if the number is stored in a variable say `x` as a string like this

```
   x = "44.00";
```

then using `parseInt` function you will get the number without the decimal places

```
   y = parseInt(x);
```

Comment: thanks anurupr, but when I have a price = 44.58 for example I wanna display it 44.58 and not only 44. parseInt will remove all the decimal part :(

Comment: then i suggest you look into this http://numeraljs.com/

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to cast a float to a int:

```
var x = parseInt("1000.0", 10); // This ignores anything behind the decimal point. Radix 10 is technically optional, but a good habit to make sure everything gets interpreted as a decimal number.
var x = Math.floor("1000.01");  // Round down. -> 1000
var x = Math.ceil("1000.01");   // Round up. -> 1001
var x = Math.round("1000.01");  // Round to nearest int. -> 1000
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have a rounding problem. It is impossible to tell without code and actual values.

You can try this workaround which is admittedly ugly:

```
// v is the value
// w is a pseudo-down-cast to an int (javascript has no ints)
w = parseInt("" + v, 10);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var f = 44.00;

var i = parseInt(f);
```

See this

Comment: actually `f` will have the integer value , there would be no need to run `parseInt` on that again

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`Math.floor()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor) (round down), [`Math.ceil()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/ceil) (round up) or [`Math.round()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round) (round to nearest integer), dependent on how you wanted to remove the decimal.

If you simply want to truncate the decimal portion, use a [bitwise operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators) (.e.g `|0`) which will treat its operand as a signed 32bit integer.

You may also be talking about the inaccuracy of decimal rounding with floating point arithmetic.

[Required Reading](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

Thanks,

Siva

Comment: @nannou please update the requirements in question properly or create another question if you want ?